# Setting up Visual Studio 2013 and SourceTree

Tags: git, visual-studio, bitbucket

Could someone help me with setting up VS 2013 to work with SourceTree?

Say, I have the VS project on my local computer and I want to work on that project together with my friend X. I've tried the following algorithms:

1) Create a project on my computer, push it to the remote repository and let my friend download it.

The scenario didn't work because git ignores some files and my friend wasn't able to run the project when he pulled it to his computer.

2) Edit the gitignore file and then repeat 1).

My friend was able to download the project and run it, but we've got some problems with the dll files from packages folder and with some text files as well; they were always changing so we had to merge FileListAbsolute.txt every time.

3) Create a project on my and X's computer so that we would have dll's on our computers.

Now we've got the problem with the project .sln file; it was different on my and my friend's computer and it contained some important data on the project so weren't able to decide how to merge it.

I've used BitBucket to host the remote repository in every case.

So, is there some algorithm to set up SourceTree to work with VS 2013 project? I've used the gitignore file from  https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore but it doesn't contain the ignore template for .sln so it's either not necessary or I should add it on my own, but in that case I don't understand why it hasn't been added yet. I'm sure that it's a really easy problem, but it looks as if I'm too idiotic to solve it on my own.

I don't want to use internal VS tool to work with git since its interface isn't very convenient and it doesn't provide as many possibilities as SourceTree does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of things going on here you should address.

Firstly I'd suggest not using a pre-made gitignore but create one step-by-step: the pre-made one might just exclude too much and by creating it yourself you'll learn more about the VS project structur/build system. Lack of knowledge about the latter seems to be the major problem here.

As a general rule you do not include anything created by the build system/editor/other tools. So no .user files, no .suo files, no editor backup files,  These are per-user preferences and normally are not shared. Also no dlls downloaded by NuGet: if they are not there NuGet will download them for you anyway. Also no project outputs of course (FileListAbsolute and the likes are project outputs). To turn it around: you include only the bare minimum needed to build.

You don't give much details about your project type/structure but here are some practical tips:

- your question explicitely mentions SourceTree but the problems you face are the same for anything built on top of git, or even any versioning system. Just something to keep in mind.
- before spending time pushing things to remote repositories and testing on other machines just test everything locally: just clone your repository into another directory (in SourceTree: Clone/New, enter path to original repo in the Source Path/URL box, specify new directory) and see if it builds
- the bare minimum needed to build, for 'normal' C++/C# projects, are all source/header files (think .cpp/.cs/.rc/.xaml/.config) files, the csproj/vcxproj file and the sln file. Nothing else.
- if you configure your projects to do out of source builds, meaning the project outputs go into a directory outside of the source code directory, so not the standard bin\Debug VS uses by default, you'll have much less trouble setting up the .gitignore and it is just less messy in general
- with the above in mind, the .gitignore template we use for practically all our projects is below

sample .gitignore:

```
*.suo
*.sdf
*.opensdf
*.user
*.ncb
*.aps
*.res
~*
packages/*
```

This gets rid of all artefacts from VS/intellisense and from NuGet packages, as far as I know. Of course if you choose to keep your intermediate and output directories in the source tree you'll have to add a lot more (plus it becomes harder to use a template since these directories might not have the same names for all projects etc). To figure out what exactly you could use SourceTree to first add just source/project files, commit, build and exclude everything changed. But as said, out of source build are imo a cleaner and easier solution.

Comment: Thank you very much. I've included the packages folder in gitIgnore (though generated by VS gitIgnore doesn't have such a line so I'm gonna test it further) and I've also added some additional paths (like that .txt file). Combined with the generated by VS file it finally worked. Thanks again.